# Websocket data is available in my angular service but not in subscription

Tags: angular, websocket, event-listener, angular7, subscribe

I am trying to send some data from my go_backend to my angular frontend.
The problem I am having is as follows:

The websocket connection is established and i am getting data inside my Service, but as soon as i try to subscribe my service no data is available!

I know i have he data in my service since i can log it there.

The code of my service looks like that:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {
  private socket: WebSocket;
  private listener: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.socket = new WebSocket(`${environment.wsUrl}/canLoop`);
    this.socket.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log('socket.info: ', this.socket.OPEN);
      this.listener.emit({'type': 'open', 'data': event});
    };
    this.socket.onclose = (event) => {
      console.log(event);
      this.listener.emit({'type': 'close', 'data': event});
    };
    this.socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log(event);
      this.listener.emit({'type': ' message', 'data': event});
    };
  }
  public close() {
    this.socket.close();
  }

  public getEventListener() {
    return this.listener;
  }

}
```

And is subscribed in my Component like that:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CanRawService } from 'src/app/services/can-raw.service';
import { WebsocketService } from 'src/app/services/websocket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-loop',
  templateUrl: './message-loop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-loop.component.scss']
})
export class MessageLoopComponent implements OnInit {

  public canMsgs: Array<any>;

  constructor(private rawSrv: CanRawService, private sockSrv: WebsocketService) {
    this.canMsgs = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sockSrv.getEventListener().subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === 'message') {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
        let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        this.canMsgs.push(data);
        console.log('lelele', event.data);
      }
      if (event.type === 'close') {
        console.log('/The socket connection has been closed');
      }
      if (event.type === 'open') {
        console.log('/The socket connection has been established');
      }

    });
  }
  // tslint:disable-next-line:use-life-cycle-interface
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sockSrv.close();
  }
}
```

I can see the data when i log it in the service but i cant manage to access it when i subscribe to it

any advice is rly appreciated!

cheers

Comment: try using subjects instead of ``EventEmitter``

Comment: using rxjs Subject solved my problem thx :)

Comment: Event emitter subscription should be avoided in services . always better to use subjects

Comment: i see thank you!
well actually I didnt use Subjet i am sorry...I did Use webSocket from rxjs, which returns a WebsocketSubject. Therefore I got another question:

Do i need a Service for that, since it is only like 1 line of code? Or should i just put it in my component?

Comment: Looks like it is very small but it internally uses a Subject . About the organization of code , it would depend on the scope of the data being sent through websockets .i don't have an opinion on it though

Answer (score 0):

Does your web socket send data as soon as you connect to it?

If so, it may be the case that the events are being emitted before your component has subscribed to the socket in your service.

That is:

```
|
| - service is created (and also the socket in constructor)
| - onopen is emitted
| - message is emitted
| - component is created
| - component is ready -> run ngOnInit() and subscribe to events
| - component is subscribed, but all events have already been emitted
```

I guess you could test this by putting a `console.log` in `ngOnInit()` to see if the events are emitted before the method has been run.

I would try to defer the connection to the websocket. Try putting your constructor code in `WebsocketService.getEventListener()`

If you're using rxjs, then this could be of help: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket